# If metabox fields has content display content

Tags: custom-field, metabox

I am try to hide the metabox fields with empty value like

```
$Product_Brennwert = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'Product_Brennwert', true);
if ( ! empty ( $Product_Brennwert ) ) {
    echo 'Brennwert
'. $Product_power . '

';
}
```

now i am try to add this in my php file but no idea how to add this in table can some on help me to do this?

part of my php file
[Single.PHP](http://pastebin.com/etJHPb0u)

Answer (score 0):

In your php file, replace:

```
<tr >
<td>Brennwert</td >
<td >'. $Product_Brennwert . '</td>
</tr >
```

with:

```
';
$Product_Brennwert = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "Product_Brennwert", true);
if(!empty($Product_Brennwert)){
    $grid_details .= "
        <tr>
        <td>Brennwert</td >
        <td>".$Product_Brennwert."</td>
        </tr>
    ";
}
$grid_details .= '
```

Comment: thx for the help its working after some modification...

Comment: Please edit my answer to add your modification, then accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

thx for the help its working after some modification... one more question i have tablle to show the info but the title show alle time if i have ther any fiels or not. how can i hide this?? the title have to show only if one of the fields have value  ... This part

```
$grid_details .= "<h2>Nährwerte &amp; Allergene</h2>
    <table class="ewtable">
<tbody>
<tr>
                        <td width="70%">
                            Nährwerte
                        </td>
                        <td width="20%">
                            pro 100g
                        </td>
                    </tr>';
$P_Energie = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "P_Energie", true);
if(!empty($P_Energie)){
    $grid_details .= "
        <tr>
        <td>Energie</td >
        <td>".$P_Energie."</td>
        </tr>
    ";
}
$P_Fett = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'P_Fett', true);
if(!empty($P_Fett)){
    $grid_details .= "
<tr>
<td>Fett</td>
<td>". $P_Fett . "</td>
</tr>";
}
```